# Which point should I pick such that the shape is a parallelogram?

Tags: complex-geometry

So I am stuck on the following problem from "Edexcel AS and A Level Modular Mathematics FP$1$":

> $z=\frac {1+7i}{4+3i}$
>   **a** Find the modulus and argument of $z$.
>   **b** Write down the modulus and argument of $z^*$.
>    In an Argand diagram, the points $A$ and $B$ represent $1+7i$ and $4+3i$ respectively and $O$ is the origin. The quadrilateral $OABC$ is a parallelogram.
>   **c** Find the complex number represented by the point $C$.
>   **d** Calculate the area of the parallelogram.

For **a**, I have found that $|z|=\sqrt 2$ and $arg (z)=\frac {\pi}4$.

For **b**, I have found that $|z^*|=\sqrt 2$ and $arg (z)=-\frac {\pi}4$.

But now I find myself in a quandary.
For **c**, I had found that $C$ could be represented with $5+10i.$

**a** and **b** are correct, but it shows $3-4i$ as the answer. Upon further thought, I realized that there were $3$ possible answers for **c**: $5+10i, 3-4i$ and $-3+4i$, as shown by:

[image: The question]

Is any answer correct in particular or do I simply choose any one and proceed to calculate the area?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @5xum I have added the screenshot

Comment: All 3 are correct as any triangle OAB can be made into one of 3 different parallelograms by adding one of three points.

Comment: @PhilH If I am not mistaken, the areas of each of these parallelograms are equal, right?

Comment: @PhilH I don't think all three are correct, since the order of the corners of the paralelogram matters.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

All three solutions yield a paralelogram, however only one solution has the corners of the paralelogram in the correct order!

Comment: Oh, I never noticed the order! I feel quite silly posting it. Thank you very much.